# twitter bootstrap typeahead for multiple input in the same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using **twitter bootstrap typeahead**  and I have these two java script functions to init the auto complete

```
  function autocomplete1(phr_type) { 
                $('.typeahead').typeahead({                                
                   name: 'arabic',                                                             
                   remote: '/ajax/autocomplate?type='+1+'&q=%QUERY',                                         
                   limit: 10 ,
                   valueKey : 'arabic_term',

                  });
}

function autocomplete2(phr_type) {
      $('.typeahead2').typeahead({                                
         name: 'arabic',                                                             
         remote: '/ajax/autocomplate?id=3&q=%QUERY',                                         
         limit: 10 ,
         valueKey : 'arabic_term',

        });
}
```

and I have two input

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead2"/>

<input type="text" class="typeahead"/>
```

and I init the auto complete using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    autocomplete1();
    autocomplete2();
});
```

but all request take the parameter from first function the **id** parameter not send in the second input when I type inside the second input.

the query parameter working well in the two function but Id not send, only the first parameter send.

so all the request will be like :

```
GET http://host/ajax/autocomplate?type=1&q=xy
GET http://host/ajax/autocomplate?type=1&q=zx
```

what i have to do solve that and send dynamic parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a different `name` in both plugin instantiation.